# Python - compare a string with a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Within an IF statement, I have a string and wish to compare it with a text file. Currently I have the following:

```
    #The part of the program that checks the user’s list of words against the external file solved.txt and displays an appropriate ‘success’ or ‘fail’ message.
if ''.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n')):
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Fail')
    print()
    #If the puzzle has not been completed correctly, the user should be allowed to continue to try to solve the puzzle or exit the program.
    continue_or_exit = input('Would you like to "continue" or "exit"? ')
    if continue_or_exit == 'continue':
       task3(word_lines, clueslistl, clueslists, clues)
    elif continue_or_exit == 'exit':
        quit()
    else:
        print()
```

However, this does not work. Even if the string and the text file are exactly the same, the command prompt will always print 'Fail'.

solved.txt:

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

Comment: It won't work for sure :D

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: What is `text` and `text.txt`? What is `str` (if not the builtin type)?

Comment: What's inside solved.txt?

Comment: The User is entering letter and symbol pairings ('A#') in order to change a list of coded words into words. The coded words has been made into a list in order to change and delete certain characters (''join).

Comment: Now it always prints 'success'?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of that, do the following:

```
if string == open('myfile.txt').read():
    print('Success')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

This uses the built-in function `open()`, and `.read()` to get the text from a file.

However, the `.read()` will result in something like this:

```
>>> x = open('test.txt').read()
>>> x
'Hello StackOverflow,\n\nThis is a test!\n\nRegards,\nA.J.\n'
>>>
```

So make sure your string contains the necessary `'\n'`s (newlines).

If your string does **not** have the `'\n'`s, then just call `''.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n'))`:

```
>>> x = ''.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n'))
>>> x
'Hello StackOverflow,This is a test!Regards,A.J.'
>>>
```

Or `' '.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n'))`:

```
>>> x = ' '.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n'))
>>> x
'Hello StackOverflow,  This is a test!  Regards, A.J. '
>>>
```

**Also, don't use `str` as a variable name. It shadows the built-in.**

Comment: ''.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n')) works, however it infinitely prints 'Success'?

Comment: Just add `break` after the `print("Success")`.