# Comparing string with text file in python

Tags: python, string, text, txt

I am trying to compare a string with the text from a text file. For some reason though, it's coming back as not the same even though I've literally copied and pasted the text from the text file to my string. I also check[how to compare a string with a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021202/python-compare-a-string-with-a-text-file) to make sure I was doing it right and I am so I am super confused on why this isn't working.

```
string = "This is working"
x = open('work.txt').read()
print(string)
print(x)
print(x is string)
```

The content of the text file is `This is working` and when I run the code I get the output below

```
This is working
This is working

False
```

Edit:
I also already tried:

```
if string == open('work.txt').read():
    print("Working")
else:
    print("Not working")
```

and that also gives out `Not working`

Comment: note that `is` and `==` are not the same thing. you can read more about the difference in the docs

Comment: @SuperStew I tried both already and it shows up false for both of them.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.  Your posted code fails to run because you didn't include your input data.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.
Since you failed to print and check types on the data values in question, we really have no way to work with your claim that `==` also fails.  Did you perhaps include a line feed in your `read`?

Comment: Replacing is for == works for me also, pretty sure that is the only problem

Comment: @Prune I feel like I have included all the code needed to reproduce this and also given the output it gives as well as stating that these should be the same.

Comment: @KittenLord Didn't work for me. I had to add `.strip()` at the end as suggested by the answer below. If that would have been the answer then I never would have needed to come here because I tried that long ago. Which is why I was so confused.

Comment: @Hercislife can you make sure that in your text file you have no trailing white space in your text file

Comment: I've explained where your post falls short of the SO posting guidelines.  Your code fails due a missing file, and you haven't traced the critical values.

Comment: @Prune I'm not sure how you're saying the code is failing. I literally just copied and pasted it and it worked. Should I also include the text file? Seems pointless because I already said what was in it.

Comment: @KittenLord I did make sure of that, yeah. I literally just copied and pasted the string over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, as mentioned you should be using `==` instead of `is` to check for equality.  Also, note the extra line between the second print statements output and your result output.  That's because the string you read from the file has a newline in it, so they're not the same string.

If you strip off the newline, they should compare:

```
string = "This is working"
x = open('work.txt').read().strip()
print(string)
print(x)
print(x == string)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you. I edited my question to show that I was using both `==` and `is` and had originally started with `==` but it wasn't working so I added `is` as well. How does the newline get added? That text file is literally just a copy and paste.

Comment: I can only guess.  It's possible whatever editor you used adds a newline to the final line of the file.  It's also possible you hit `Enter` after `Ctrl`+`V` without thinking and saved it.  Whatever the case, clearly there's a newline in the file.

Comment: I think Emacs must have just added it on its own because I actively tried deleting it just now and it kept coming back. Thank you for this.

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
print(x == string)
```

Comment: Also shows up false. I tried that as well already.

Comment: `x` has a linefeed character at the end, hence the blank line before `False`.